# Does image quality reduce everytime I scale an image up and down using transform tool in Photoshop cc?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, creative-cloud, scale

I don't use photoshop often but am not clear on image resizing. I am wanting to make a photo collage of images similar to the below. I will need to play around with scale a bit using the transform tool but I am not sure whether this reduces the quality each time I scale the image up. I don't have or know exact dimensions of each image its more a matter of figuring out at what scale it looks good.

[image]

I've had a look at the below tutorial about resizing images but I don't think its quite what I need for what I'm doing.

https://photoshopcafe.com/resize-images-photoshop-keep-quality/

Comment: Yes. Rescaling or transforming raster images in Photoshop is destructive since the image will be resampled each time you do it, and the more times you do it the worse the quality will get. The excepted answer is the best way to avoid that. Another way is to use software like Illustrator to place the images. In Illustrator rescaling or transforming a raster image doesn't result in resampling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the layer to a smart object and then use the transform tool to resize.

Answer (score 0):

Converting each image into a smart object is the way to go. To do that, just select the layer/image, right click and choose - **convert to smart object**. You have to do this for all of your images.

[image: Smart Oject]